# Translate Post date (month) of china language

Tags: date, plugin-polylang

How can I translate with the date output format like this: `AUG 2020` with php wp or my wordpress site is currently using the polylang plugin.
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code that's generating the date? I'd expect Polylang to set the PHP locale so PHP-generated dates would just be correct, so it's probably something else, but I don't know the plugin.

Comment: Hello @Rup. 
Here is the code that shows the date in post <?php echo get_the_date('M Y');?>. 
I am using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set translation of date/time format from here while Polylang plugin was actived:

```
dashboard menu -> Languages -> Strings translations
```

for example:

- for date_format English translation: **m/d/Y**
- for date_format Chinese translation: **Y年n月j日**

Comment: Thank you so much.